# Is there any possibility to create a new column based on the keywords list

Tags: python, pandas, list, conditional-statements

Is there any possibility to create a new column based on the keywords list?

```
Keywords = ["A", "B"]
```

I have data like this:

```
Location             Type          
Ger                  A          
Ger                  F
Ger                  C     
Ned                  D
Ned                  A
Ned                  B
Aus                  C
US                   B
```

I would like to create a new column if the keyword exists in the Type column and if 2 keywords exist then the value should both keyword with a comma. I am having a problem because I have to check also location first and then type...

```
Location             Type          NewType
Ger                  A             A
Ger                  F             A
Ger                  C             A
Ned                  D             A,B
Ned                  A             A,B
Ned                  B             A,B
Aus                  C             NaN
US                   B             B
```

Is there any way other than `if-else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use `groupby` and `map`:

```
m = df['Type'].isin(keywords)
s = df[m].groupby('Location')['Type'].agg(','.join)
df['NewType'] = df['Location'].map(s)
```

**Details:**

Create boolean mask with [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to test for the values in `Type` that exists in `keywords` list:

```
print(m)

0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6    False
7     True
Name: Type, dtype: bool
```

filter the rows using the above mask and `groupby` on `Location` then `agg` `Type` using `join`:

```
print(s)

Location
Ger      A
Ned    A,B
US       B
Name: Type, dtype: object
```

[`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the values from the above aggregated frame to the original `df` based on `Location`

```
print(df)

  Location Type NewType
0      Ger    A       A
1      Ger    F       A
2      Ger    C       A
3      Ned    D     A,B
4      Ned    A     A,B
5      Ned    B     A,B
6      Aus    C     NaN
7       US    B       B
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There is one problem that if "Type" has 2 times repeated value then it shows like `A,A` which I don't want... Is there any solution for that?

Comment: @s_khan92 You can test for duplicates while creating `boolean mask `like `m = df['Type'].isin(keywords) & ~df.duplicated()`.

Comment: Still getting the same duplicated values

Comment: @s_khan92 Do you have more than two columns in actual dataframe? If so then you have to use `m = df['Type'].isin(keywords) & ~df.duplicated(['Location', 'Type'])`

Comment: Yes.. 4 columns

Comment: @s_khan92 Check **`m = df['Type'].isin(keywords) & ~df.duplicated(['Location', 'Type'])`**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function and apply it on `df['Location']`:

```
def func(x):
    temp=list(df[df.Location==x]['Type'])
    return ','.join(i for i in Keywords if i in temp)

df['NewType']=df.Location.apply(lambda x: func(x))
df['NewType'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Location Type NewType
0      Ger    A       A
1      Ger    F       A
2      Ger    C       A
3      Ned    D     A,B
4      Ned    A     A,B
5      Ned    B     A,B
6      Aus    C     NaN
7       US    B       B
```